# Bind data from db to dropdownlist + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, html-select

I have a question about using a dropdownlist in ASP.net MVC.

This is my situation:

**Create view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Deliverable", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EventViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Thumbnail, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image , new {type="file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

After the 'VideoURL' I would like to have a Dropdownlist with values that are stored in my database. Most of the tutorials that I find don't bind the values in the dropdownlist to the database.

I insert the values in my db in my backoffice so I can't insert them in frontoffice...

This is my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(DeliverableViewModel model)
    {
        var afstudeerrichtingen = (repository.GetAfstudeerrichtingen()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                model.Image.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] data = target.ToArray();

                model.Thumbnail.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] datatwo = target.ToArray();

                users usr = userrepo.FindByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
                model.UsernameID = usr.user_id;

                repository.AddDeliverable(model.Title, model.Description, model.UsernameID, data, datatwo, model.VideoUrl, model.Afstudeerrichting);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

In sent the values to my repository where I save it in my database.

This is my DeliverableViewModel:

```
public class DeliverableViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Thumbnail")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "VideoUrl")]
    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "AfstudeerrichtingID")]
    public int AfstudeerrichtingID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Afstudeerrichting")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    public long UsernameID { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know what I have to add in my view & controller to make this work?

The values are in my tabel "Afstudeerrichtingen" in my mysql database
- afstuddeerichting_id
- afstudeerrichting_name

Comment: Are you just asking how to create a DropDownList based on data you're getting back from your database?

Comment: Yes, maybe you have a good tutorial or so? I now get my data in a list I get from the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dropdownlist in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AfstudeerrichtingID, 
   new SelectList(ViewBag.Richtingen, 
    "AfstudeerrichtingId", "AfstudeerrichtingName"))
```

Add your Afstudeerrichting collection to the ViewBag in the controller:

```
ViewBag.Richtingen = afstudeerrichtingen;
```

Assuming that that collection contains the properties AfstudeerrichtingId and AfstudeerrichtingName, as used in the view.

Another thing to do is change your AfstudeerrichtingID to string, and translate it to/from int in your repository class.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it at home!